# Databinding a list (in an object) to a combobox in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, combobox

VB 2008  .NET 3.5

I have a custom "Shipment" object that contains a list of "ShippingRate" objects.  This list of "ShippingRates" is accessible through a property "Shipment.PossibleShippingRates."  That property simply returns a copy of the list of "ShippingRate" for that particular Shipment.

My UI layer receives a list of "Shipment" objects from the BLL.  This list is databound to a datagridview, and shows details relevant to the Shipment such as Shipping Address, etc.

I want to bind the "Shipment.PossibleShippingRates" property to a combobox, such that when the user changes the grid row, the combobox reflects the "PossibleShippingRates" for that "Shipment."

In addition, I need a way to store the "ShippingRate" they selected from the combobox for later use.

I have tried a few ideas, but none of them work properly.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't the simplest solution be to tie a TextChanged or SelectedIndexChanged event to any/all fields in the datagrid that need to trigger a refresh of the combobox?