# DataBinding a Combobox to custom object fails to show data

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, data-binding, binding

I'm having a problem with databinding an object to a combobox in VB.NET (VS2008/.NET 3.5). Please take a look at this simplified version of my code:

```
Friend Class clDocument
    Private _items as New List(Of clDocumentItems)

    <System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Items")> _
    <System.ComponentModel.Bindable(True)> _
    Public Property Items() As List(Of clDocumentItems)
        Get
            Return _items
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of clDocumentItems))
            _items = value
            RaiseEvent ItemsChanged(Me, New EventArgs)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event ItemsChanged As EventHandler
End Class
Friend Class clDocumentItems
    Private _uid as String = ""
    Private _docnumber as String = ""

    <System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("UID")> _
    <System.ComponentModel.Bindable(True)> _
    Public Property UID() As String
        Get
            Return _uid
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _uid = value
            RaiseEvent UIDChanged(Me, New EventArgs)
        End Set
    End Property
    <System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Document")> _
    <System.ComponentModel.Bindable(True)> _
    Public Property DocNumber() As String
        Get
            Return _docnumber
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _docnumber = value
            RaiseEvent DocNumberChanged(Me, New EventArgs)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event UIDChanged As EventHandler
    Public Event DocNumberChanged As EventHandler
End Class
```

Somewhere else, we got this code:

```
Private Sub cmd_go_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmd_go.Click
        'Try to load the object with data, this works well
        Dim _document as New clDocument
        _document.Load(somevalue)

        cmb_docs.DataSource = Nothing
        cmb_docs.Items.Clear()
        If _document.UID = "" Then Exit Sub 'Object wasn't loaded so get out

        'Create the binding.     
        cmb_docs.ValueMember = "UID"
        cmb_docs.DisplayMember = "DocNumber"
        cmb_docs.DataSource = _document.Items
End Sub
```

Now, the problem is that the ComboBox is populated with as many items as there are objects in _document.Items, but it doesn't passes real data -The combobox is filled with "Namespace.clDocumentItems" strings. Please note that similar code works perfectly when bound to regular class properties (String, integer, etc).

Now, I can guess by using the debugger's reflection that it is because the Datsource is receiving a List of objects instead of fields, but then again I don't know how to avoid that without having to create another Array or List with just those values and passing THAT to the Datasource property...

I explored the site for something similar, the only thing that came close was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043397/databinding-a-list-in-an-object-to-a-combobox-in-vb-net) that went unanswered 3 years ago, so I hope to have better luck today ;)

Thanks for your time!

EDIT: Below I add the code I used for databinding to a DataGridView, as requested in the comments.

```
    Private WithEvents _bs as New BindingSource

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        Dim column As DataGridViewColumn = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        column.DataPropertyName = "Document"
        column.Name = "colDoc"
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(column)

        _bs.DataSource = _document.Items 
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = _bs
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually nothing at all wrong with your code as you have it written above (I copied it into a new WinForms app, supplied some default values, and it worked correctly).

There are two possible reasons that your implementation may not be working:

1. If there is a typo in DisplayMember.
2. If the access level of the DisplayMember property prevents the
   combobox from accessing it.

If the property cannot be found or accessed, .Net drops back to the default implementation of using the object's ToString method. So one quick and dirty fix would be to override the ToString method of clDocument and return DocNumber. That should resolve the display issue, but not the underlying cause of the problem, which will require a little more research.

Comment: Well it turns out your point #2 was correct.

I too had a suspicion on the classes being "Friend" instead of public. It turns out that:

- Using that code I can bind to "direct" instances, no problem at all, even if defined Friend.
- But if the object is nested, said nested object has to be Public, even if the parent is Friend. Otherwise it will not bind to the property.

Funnily enough, using those nested Friend classes did not cause any problems on a DataGrid control using BindingSource... >.>

Thanks again!

Comment: @KalaNag how did you bind it using BindingSource? Could you give me an  example?

Answer (score 0):

ok, The problem was the comboBox was faulty. Removing the control from the form and adding it again solved the problem. I accept the answer because it contains useful information.

Thanks